# Error in using fold_left in OCaml

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I am trying to convert the integers in a list to their corresponding ASCII values and then concatenating them to form a string. This is what I tried:

```
# let l = [65;66;67];;
# List.fold_left (fun x y ->  char_of_int x ^ char_of_int y) "" l;;
```

I am getting the following error :

```
Error: This expression has type char but an expression was expected of type
         string
```

marking the `char_of_int x`  as an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error occurs, because the OCaml operator `^` will only accept two strings, it cannot directly concatenate two characters. In order to build the string, you first have to convert the individual characters to strings (of length 1). Then you can concatenate these short strings.

```
# let chars = List.map char_of_int l;;
val chars : char list = ['A'; 'B'; 'C']
# let strings = List.map (String.make 1) chars;;
val strings : string list = ["A"; "B"; "C"]
# String.concat "" strings;;
- : string = "ABC"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have trouble converting this to a function that takes a list as argument. How should I convert it? 

I tried this :
`let addNum lst =               
      let chars = List.map char_of_int l in
      let strings = List.map (String.make 1) chars in
      String.concat "" strings;;
`

But it only prints "ABC" no matter what the list members are.

Comment: @newuser You wrote `l` where you meant `lst`, and you still have `l` defined as `[65;66;67]`.